# Not selecting Max Value

Tags: sql

[image]

I am using the query

```
select max(entry_no) from tbl_Invmaster
```

but its giving me ans 9 however the max value is 10.

Comment: What are the data types in use?

Comment: is that column a string-ish type? In that case max will select based on alphabetical ordering, and 9 would be the max

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the numbers in a `VARCHAR` column. Ordering in those fields is by [alphabetcal order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order). That way `9` is bigger than `10`. Explanation from the link:

> To determine which of two strings comes first in alphabetical order, their first letters are compared. If they differ, then the string whose first letter comes earlier in the alphabet is the one which comes first in alphabetical order. If the first letters are the same, then the second letters are compared, and so on. If a position is reached where one string has no more letters to compare while the other does, then the first (shorter) string is deemed to come first in alphabetical order.

Your best solution is not to store numbers in `VARCHAR` columns but instead use the appropriate type, eg `INT`. That way your query would return the correct result.

If that is not an option for you, you could `CAST` the column to an integer type. Eg in SQL Server you would write:

```
select max(CAST(entry_no AS INT)) from tbl_Invmaster
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max( to_number( entry_no )) from tbl_invmaster
```

Comment: you 'd rather explain why your code will solve the op question.